# Retrieve dbpedia rdf file

Tags: rdf, dbpedia

i'm trying to add more terms in Drupal taxonomy.
I integrated opencalais module and now i want to import rdf definitions found in dbpedia.
My question is: where exactly can i find the rdf file from dbpedia site? I can't seem to figure it out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I can't help with the taxonomy and opencalais modules, but DBpedia files can be downloaded from here: http://dbpedia.org/Downloads36

Comment: Thank you but i need an online rdf definition file as Drupal cannot load rdf ontologies from file system.

Comment: Can you just download the file that you need (probably the DBpedia Ontology OWL file?) and upload it to your own webspace?